# Get Line Item value from XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Need to get Line Item value from below XML using xslt.

Input Xml :

```
<Root>
<Table>
<Row1 ColumnA_1="1A" ColumnB_1="1B" ColumnC_1="1B"/>
<Row2 ColumnA_2="2A" ColumnB_2="2B" ColumnC_2="2C"/>
<Row3 ColumnA_3="3A" ColumnB_3="3B" ColumnC_3="3C"/>
<Row4 .......


<Rown>

</Table>
</Root>
```

we can get Tag value without loop using below code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Root/Table/Row1/@ColumnA_1"/>
<xsl:value-of select="/Root/Table/Row2/@ColumnA_2"/>
```

How we can get Line Item value using below loop ?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Root/Table">
   <xsl:for-each select="./*">
   <Row><xsl:value-of select="/Root/Table/*/@ColumnA_ + position()"/</Row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you want to generate? If you process all child elements of the `Table` and you seem to want to map each child element to a `Row` in the output, which content should a `Row` in the output have?

Comment: Output XML format :

<Root>
<Table>

<Row>  
<ColumnB>1B</ColumnB>
</Row>

<Row>  
<ColumnB>2B</ColumnB>
</Row>

<Row>
<ColumnB>3B</ColumnB>
</Row>

<Row>  
<ColumnB>nB</ColumnB>
</Row>

</Table>
</Root>